# Aligning animation with direction Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, direction

So the problem is when I move the character(he is not humanoid) his walk animation is not aligned with the direction of his movement, for example, if I press W then he moves forward but his walk animation turns 90 degrees left, I have no idea where the problem might be. Here's the code I have:

```c#
public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float MovSpeed = 3;

    public float SmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float TurnSmoothVelocity;

    public float SpeedSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float SmoothVelocity;
    float CurrentSpeed;

    Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

        Vector2 Input = new Vector2(UnityEngine.Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), UnityEngine.Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        Vector2 InputDirection = Input.normalized;

        if (InputDirection != Vector2.zero)
        {
            float TargetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(InputDirection.x, InputDirection.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y , TargetRotation, ref TurnSmoothVelocity, SmoothTime);
        }

        float targetSpeed = MovSpeed * InputDirection.magnitude;
        CurrentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(CurrentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref SmoothVelocity, SmoothTime);

        transform.Translate(transform.forward * CurrentSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        float animationSpeedPercent = .5f * InputDirection.magnitude;
        animator.SetFloat("SpeedPercent", animationSpeedPercent, SpeedSmoothTime, Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Animated Object should be the Child of the Controller that has this Script assigned.

Just make an EmptyGameObject, add this script and parent your Animated Character under that Object.

If it's still not working correctly there might be something wrong with the Animation. The Script looks right to me.